# Remove or replace a ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER character

Tags: php, unicode

I want to remove [ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm) character from a string but using `str_replace` wasn't useful.

Comment: Can you please post a code you've used for removing the character?

Comment: $old = "علی‌ها"; and i want $new = "علیها";

Answer (score 7, accepted):

str_replace should solves this, as long as you're careful with what you're replacing.

```
// \xE2\x80\x8C is ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER
$foo = "foo\xE2\x80\x8Cbar";

print($foo . " - " . strlen($foo) . "\n");
$foo = str_replace("\xE2\x80\x8C", "", $foo);
print($foo . " - " . strlen($foo) . "\n");
```

Outputs as expected:

```
foo‌bar - 9
foobar - 6
```

Comment: Do you know what is the title of that kind of codes? (I mean`\xE2\x80\x8C`) what is its title?

Comment: @Kermani Usually just [escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) or escape codes; they can be / are different for each language, but most implement a common subset (such as \x, \n, \r, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

str_replace will do what you want, but PHP does not have very good native support for Unicode. The following will do what you ask. json_decode has been used to get the Unicode char, since PHP does not support the \u syntax.

```
<?php
$unicodeChar = json_decode('"\u200c"');
$string = 'blah'.$unicodeChar.'blah';
echo str_replace($unicodeChar, '', $string);
?>
```

edit: While my method works, I would suggest you use fiskfisk's solution. It is less hacky than using json_decode.

Comment: For anyone coming across this, PHP added support for Unicode literals in PHP 7.0 (2015) using the syntax `"\u{200C}"`