# Remove or match a Unicode Zero Width Space PHP

Tags: php, replace, unicode

I have a text in Burmese language, UTF-8.  I am using PHP to work with the text.  At some point along the way, some ZWSPs have crept in and I would like to remove them.  I have tried two different ways of removing the characters, and neither seems to work.

First I have tried to use:

```
  $newBody = str_replace("&#8203;", "", $newBody);
```

to search for the HTML entity and remove it, as this is how it appears under Web Inspector.  The spaces don't get removed.  I have also tried it as:

```
  $newBody = str_replace("&#8203", "", $newBody);
```

and get the same no result.

The second method I tried was found on this question [Remove ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER character from a string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481688/remove-zero-width-non-joiner-character-from-a-string-in-php)

which looked like this:

```
 $newBody = str_replace("\xE2\x80\x8C", "", $newBody);
```

but I also got no result.  The ZWSP was not removed.

```
An example word in the text ($newBody) looks like this : ယူ​&#8203;က​&#8203;ရိန်
And I want to make it look like this : ယူကရိန်း
```

Any ideas?  Would a preg_replace work better somehow?

So I did try

```
$newBody = preg_replace("/\xE2\x80\x8B/", "", $newBody);
```

and it appears to be workings, but now there is another issue.

```
<a class="defined" title="Ukraine">ယူ&#8203;က&#8203;ရိန်း</a>
```

gets transformed into

```
<a class="defined _tt_t_" title="Ukraine" style="font-family: 'Masterpiece Uni Sans', TharLon, Myanmar3, Yunghkio, Padauk, Parabaik, 'WinUni Innwa', 'Win Uni Innwa', 'MyMyanmar Unicode', Panglong, 'Myanmar Sangam MN', 'Myanmar MN';">ယူကရိန်း</a>
```

I don't want it to add all that extra stuff.  Any ideas why this is happening?  Apart from coming up with some way to target only the text in between  , is there another way to prevent the preg_replace from adding all this extra stuff?  Btw, using google chrome on a mac.  It seems to act a bit differently with firefox...

Comment: Can you provide a short example of what `$newBody` might contain, and what you would like it to contain instead? The best way to remove nuisance characters is to understand how they got there in the first place.

Comment: That last part is strange. Did you view the output using "inspect element" or "view source"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This:

```
$newBody = str_replace("&#8203;", "", $newBody);
```

presumes the text is HTML entity encoded.  This:

```
$newBody = str_replace("\xE2\x80\x8C", "", $newBody);
```

should work if the offending characters are not encoded, but matches the wrong character (0xe2808c). To match the same character as #8203; you need 0xe2808b:

```
$newBody = str_replace("\xE2\x80\x8B", "", $newBody);
```

Comment: so, that doesn't appear to be working, but I did try      $newBody = preg_replace("/\xE2\x80\x8B/", "", $newBody);
and it did work.

Comment: Great!  FYI, when I copy/pasted your sample I found it has both encoded and unencoded examples of <200b>, so I presume you are also still doing a replace on '&#8203;'

Comment: I did try replacing '&#8203;' before, but I am not now.  So maybe it's leftover.  How did you see the encoded unencoded examples?  I'm still a bit green regarding all this unicode stuff...  And any ideas regarding the last part of the question I just added?

Comment: The html entity encoded strings (&#8203;) I could see in my browser.  The unencoded example I could only see when I pasted your example into vi (a text editor commonly used in Linux/Unix), where it shows up as "<200b>" (the UTF-16 representation in hex) - though this is dependent on how my vi is set-up.

A good starting point for getting your head around character set issues is: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: `str_replace("\xE2\x80\x8C", "", $content);` worked for me

Answer (score 10):

If you want to remove zero width space characters from an UTF-8 string:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x{200B}-\x{200D}\x{FEFF}]/u', '', $string);
```

References:

- https://gist.github.com/ahmadazimi/b1f1b8f626d73728f7aa (php)
- [Remove zero-width space characters from a JavaScript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305797/remove-zero-width-space-characters-from-a-javascript-string) (js)